# django access database from crispy form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I'm working on a blog for a client that is using crispy form to make their writing's easier. I have the ability to add an image to the blog - only one and at the top of the post. My client wants to add other pictures throughout the post. The crispy form allows them to do this but only by way of a full http link. This means they would have to understand how the admin of the site works to be able to find the pic they want and use it here. Is there a way to have them be able to find the picture from the database and use that pictures url right on this screen?

Here is a screenshot of what I mean:
[image]

Comment: Take a look at [`django-filer`](https://github.com/divio/django-filer)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to add a simple bootstrap dropdown with each picture in the database, sorted by most recent, and a copy url button. If someone can come up with a better solution, that would be best.